# Intellij - build artifact

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-15

When I build a Jar in intellij (using "build artifacts...") it generates a jar that has invalid signature.
To solve it I always need to go inside the jar to META-INF folder and delete ORACLE_J.SF and ORACLE_J.RSA.

Any idea why it happens/how to solve it?

Comment: I never have that problem.  Take a look at how you're setting up the artifact creation.

Comment: nothing fancy, I go to "Artifacts -> + ->Jar -> From modules with dependencies" and then I create the jar like i described in my post here

Comment: Build "from modules with dependencies...." or empty JAR?

Comment: from modules with dependencies

Comment: because i have dependencies and i want them all inside the jar

Comment: You should use Maven for that.

Comment: I have a simple project with local jars i depend on, i dont want to add maven for this particular project

Comment: "local jars" - this is a project to build those JARs and include them?  I've done that manually, too.  Now I'd recommend that Maven would be a better way.  I would have resisted just as you are now.  Your choice.

Comment: I know I can do it with maven, I can also delete intellij and work with eclipse, but I want to know what causes this problem and fix it

Comment: Not IntelliJ. Why drop back to an inferior product like Eclipse?  Doesn't happen to me. Voting to close.

Comment: @duffymo just because it doesn't happen to you doesn't mean my question is irrelevant